# How to solve this Cauchy equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'+2y=2e^xy^{1/2}$$

What I tried:

$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}} +2\sqrt{y} =2e^x$$

$$z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$$

$$z' = \frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}$$

$$2z' = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}}$$

$$z' + yz = e^x$$

something is exactly wrong here because I got different variables:/

Comment: **Hint:** How about trying $$z = \sqrt{y}$$ That will make it so you can use an Integrating Factor.

Comment: Your $z'$ is wrong. Try again with $z=\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: Typically, one would solve [an equation in the following form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) with the change of variable $z=y^{1-n}$:
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
Here, $n=1/2$, which suggests the substitution $z=\sqrt{y}$, as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: @MyGlasses well, as I remember the workflow we have to devide equation with $y$ in the gratest power then make substitution like $ z =1/y^n$ where $n$ is the gratest power and then find $z'$ as an implicit derivative, here is $y^{1/2}$ is greatest

Comment: For $y'+2y=2e^xy^{1/2}$ it is $z=1/y^{1/2-1}=\sqrt{y}$

Comment: This is correct now, but with substitution doesn't work! Try to see.

Comment: @MyGlasses. am I nominally right that if there's square root in bernulli's equation we have to put $z = \sqrt{y}$ and not the $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$ ?

Comment: I think yes!...square root in right side of bernulli's equation, of course!

Comment: @MyGlasses, and also as final step, If I understood correctly we have to devide boths sides with the greatest power anyway :], we will just end up with another substitution

Answer (score 1):

Solving a more general problem:

$$\text{y}\space'\left(x\right)+\text{n}\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{n}\cdot\exp\left(x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)^\frac{1}{\text{n}}\tag1$$

Let $\mathcal{V}\left(x\right)=\text{y}\left(x\right)^{1-\frac{1}{\text{n}}}$:

$$\mathcal{V}\space'\left(x\right)+\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot\mathcal{V}\left(x\right)=\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot\exp\left(x\right)\tag2$$

Let $\rho\left(x\right)=\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)$, multiplying both sides by $\rho\left(x\right)$ and substitute:

$$\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\right)\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\rho\left(x\right)\cdot\mathcal{V}\space'\left(x\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\right)\cdot\mathcal{V}\left(x\right)=\rho\left(x\right)\cdot\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot\exp\left(x\right)\tag4$$

Now, apply the reverse product rule:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\cdot\mathcal{V}\left(x\right)\right)=\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot\exp\left(x+\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\tag5$$

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\int\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\cdot\mathcal{V}\left(x\right)\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot\exp\left(x+\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag6$$

So:

$$\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\cdot\mathcal{V}\left(x\right)=\frac{\text{n}-1}{\text{n}}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)+\text{C}\tag7$$

We end up with:

$$\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-1\right)\cdot x\right)\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)^{1-\frac{1}{\text{n}}}=\frac{\text{n}-1}{\text{n}}\cdot\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)+\text{C}\tag8$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}} + \sqrt{y} = e^x $$

The substitution $z = \sqrt{y}$ gives

$$ z' + z = e^x $$

You can use any first-order method to solve this. The solution is something like
$$ z = \frac{1}{2}e^x + ce^{-x} $$